# three tables, table A has one-to-many relation with table B and table B has one-to-many relation with table C then how to relate table A and table C

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Code**

Category.php

```
public function sub_category()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sub_Category::class);
}

id name
1  shirts
2  pants
```

Sub_Category.php

```
 public function category()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
 }

public function product()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}

id cat_id name
1  1      formal shirts
2  1      casual shirts
```

Product.php

```
public function sub_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Sub_Category::class);
}

id sub_cat_id name
1  1          Raymonds Formal Shirt
2  2          Raymonds Casual Shirt
5  1          Levis Formal Shirt
10 2          VanHuesen Casual Shirt
```

**Question**

is there any way to communicate Category and Product.
ie: when click shirts(category, display all four shirts in product table in a page.

Comment: please share what have you tried regarding this?

Comment: what you are looking for is hasManyThrough relation, please visit https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Has Many Through Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)
It's made exactly for that reason, here is an example, in your `Category.php`:

```php
public function products() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class,Sub_Category::class);
}
```

Comment: I read what you mentioned but still I have doubts..

Comment: category.php                                                                                         public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, Sub_Category::class);
    }

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.sub__category_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `products`.*, `sub__categories`.`category_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `products` inner join `sub__categories` on `sub__categories`.`id` = `products`.`sub__category_id` where `sub__categories`.`category_id` in (1)) (View: E:\Xampp\htdocs\Projects\laravel\HappyOutlets\resources\views\admin\front_layouts\header.blade.php)

Comment: share info..pls